# How to solve MySQL user access error in Dockerized web application while connecting MySQL database with PHP?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, portainer

I'm currently building a webapp that connects to a database to login to the webapp. The webapp is already created and I'm currently building the stuff in containers. But now I want to add a database in a container (with the website also in container) to get login working. What is working is that I can register a account with e-mail, name and password. This is also stored in the MySQL database. But when I'm trying to login I got the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Access denied for user 'my_user'@'172.31.0.3' (using password: YES) in /var/www/html/login.php:22 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/login.php(22): mysqli->__construct('db', 'my_user', Object(SensitiveParameterValue), 'database') #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/login.php on line 22

It looks like that the user my_user hasn't got the right permissions. I also did granted all permissions to the account.

---

*Docker image*:

```
FROM php:apache
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli
```

*Docker compose*:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  web:
    image: web-db-0206
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - /home/user1/testwebdb:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my_password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=database
      - MYSQL_USER=my_user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=my_password
    volumes:
      - /home/user1/final_dockerfiles/website-database-test/db_data:/var/lib/mysql

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      - PMA_HOST=10.174.80.3
    restart: always
    
volumes:
  db_data:
```

*register.php*:

```
<?php
$servername = "db";
$username = "my_user";
$password = "my_password";
$database = "database";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Check if the form is submitted
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") {
    // Get the form data
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    // Insert user data into the database
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (email, name, password) VALUES ('$email', '$name', '$password')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === true) {
        echo "User registered successfully!";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
}

// Close the connection
$conn->close();

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="register.php" method="POST">
    <label>Email:</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" required><br><br>

    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" required><br><br>

    <label>Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" required><br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>

</body>
</html>

***login.php***
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    // If the user is already logged in, redirect to the landing page
    header("Location: landing.php");
    exit;
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    // Database connection details
    $servername = "db";
    $username = "my_user";
    $password = "my_password";
    $database = "database";

    // Get form data
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    // Prepare and bind the SQL statement
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = ? AND password = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $email, $password);

    // Execute the statement
    $stmt->execute();

    // Store the result
    $stmt->store_result();

    if ($stmt->num_rows === 1) {
        // Login successful
        $stmt->bind_result($user_id);
        $stmt->fetch();

        // Store user_id in session
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;

        // Redirect to the landing page
        header("Location: landing.php");
        exit;
    } else {
        // Login failed
        $login_error = "Invalid email or password";
    }

    // Close the statement and connection
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <?php if (isset($login_error)) { ?>
        <p><?php echo $login_error; ?></p>
    <?php } ?>
    <form action="login.php" method="POST">
        <label>Email:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" required><br><br>

        <label>Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" required><br><br>

        <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This covers your Docker side, but what about the `mysqli` side?

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing an access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Any modern [development framework](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavours from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](https://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files.

Comment: I already created the php-codes. The websites are already working with a RESTfull service. Thats all fine. It needs only to be accessible when logged in. That's what I need.

Comment: @tadman mysqli side contains the following:

CREATE DATABASE database;

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: I get that you have PHP code, but the problem here is likely *in* that code. Are you sure you set your MySQL credentials correctly? That you're connecting to the correct database? We can't tell, we can't see. "Access denied" is often a case of using the wrong password.

Comment: That doesn't help at all either. This likely relates *specifically* to your `new mysqli` call.

Comment: Yes the code is good, because it can register a user in the database. Im sorry i didnt provide the code. I just putted in there

Comment: It's obviously *not* good because you're getting an error with it. Don't assume. Always question if it's correct through testing. A) Is `172.31.0.3` the correct IP? B) Does that user get created via `%` as the host to allow remote access? C) Are you supplying the same password specified in the `Dockerfile`?  D) Are you able to log in to that MySQL server via the command-line or MySQL Workbench using those credentials?

Comment: Can you read the updated question please. A: yes, its a container, I can access the database with phpmyadmin and with mysql container. B: No, the user doesn't need access to the db. Only to the webportal. C) yes. D) yes.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](https://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: As I suspected you've got *multiple* implementations of your database connection code. This is an extremely bad habit to get into. You should have *one* that you use everywhere you need it via an `include`. Even better, you should stop writing all of this yourself and use a framework as this development practice is not sustainable, it only leads to increased mess and technical debt at an alarming rate.

Comment: It is for testing purposes now only. So I know the risks. I'm a IT security student.

Comment: If you "know the risks" you'd know you **never, ever** do anything like this. Period. It's just reckless, irresponsible, and unprofessional. It takes the same amount of time to do it properly. The SQL holes you create here can have catastrophic consequences, *especially* because those passwords are stored as plain-text.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But can you actually help me or just disagreeing me

Comment: I've given an answer, and, as you've noticed, a lot of important advice you should at least acknowledge.

Comment: Okay, but thats not the point now. I only asked for information to make it work. Not your opinion and the security risks. How I work is, make it first functional and then add the security. That's my way

Comment: "How I work is, make it first functional and then add the security." is effectively saying "Yeah, my code is dangerous and could bring down the entire company, but it's fine because I'll fix it later." You know why that's bad? Because sometimes that stuff slips through. Code like you have here should not exist. It shouldn't be written, checked into version control, or deployed. Writing this with placeholder values is *not hard* and should be automatic.

Comment: Please, don't make excuses for code like this, just write better code. It'll help you immeasurably through your career.

Answer (score 0):

In that code you stomp your `$password` configuration parameter with `$password` as in the user's password.

This is why separating your database connection into a separate function you can `include` is way, *way* better than this approach.